# Emacs: How to start Local python interpreter when editing a remote python file via tramp

Tags: emacs, tramp, python-mode

On Emacs,  when I start python with <kbd>C-c !</kbd> while editing a remote python file (using tramp - plinkx: on windows), the python interpreter is started on the remote host.

Is there any way I can edit the remote python file and start a local python interpreter?

I am using [python-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode#toc1) (not the default python.el)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode#toc1) creates an inferior process via `'make-comint`, which uses `'start-file-process`, which creates the process relative to the variable `'default-directory`.  So there are a few ways you can tackle this beast.

The first is to change `'default-directory` to be something local, like:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq default-directory "~"))
```

That has the downside that <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> now behaves differently (starting at `~`).

Another is to change the `'default-directory` just for the invocation of `'py-shell`, like so (untested):

```
(defadvice py-shell (around py-shell-different-directory activate)
  "set default-directory just for py-shell"
  (let ((default-directory "~"))
    ad-do-it))
```